# What are the backwards compatibility and API changes in SDL Web 8.5 compared to SDL Web 8

Tags: web8, core-service, web8.5, web8-cu1

This might be a bit of a random question, but there must be many developers who have some experience of code that broke after an upgrade. I am in particular looking for breaking changes when upgrading from Web 8.1 to Web 8.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I have quite the opposite experience, when developing DXA we didn't need to change/fix anything when upgrading from Web 8 to Web 8.5.

There are backwards compatibility breaks and API changes in the 8.5 release of course, they are fully documented [here.](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-3AC0A40D-BD2E-4097-B217-F70D4122A1B1) 
Some highlights which might be valid for you could be:

- User privileges no longer identical to Access Token privileges
- Work Items contains dynamic versions, not versionless items
- Undo publish feature dropped

Details of these can be found [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-32881277-C34F-45AB-847D-BB967CC2AD99) and [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-51911BD3-DD1F-4D7A-A980-463062CB377B).